# _grokparsefailure when including "semantic" portion

Tags: rspec, logstash, grok, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I'm testing my logstash configuration with an rspec to match a basic tomcat log, but when I specify fields in my grok pattern it fails (without the fields, it succeeds!).

```
config <<-CONFIG
filter {
  grok {
    patterns_dir -> "./patterns"
    pattern => "%{CATALINA_DATESTAMP:logTimestamp} %{JAVACLASS} %{WORD}"
  }
}
CONFIG

sample 'Jul 15, 2015 9:33:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log'
```

//EDIT: corrected TOMCAT_DATESTAMP to CATALINA_DATESTAMP, which is:

```
CATALINA_DATESTAMP %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY}, 20%{YEAR} %{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND}) (?:AM|PM)
```

When the ":logTimestamp" part is in the pattern, nothing is matched.  when it's removed it matches the line... any ideas on why?  Is this user error, install error or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably caused by the `TOMCAT_DATESTAMP` pattern. When you take a look at the [grok default patterns for java](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/java) you'll see that it doesn't match your input.

This is the pattern definition:

```
TOMCAT_DATESTAMP 20%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} %{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND}) %{ISO8601_TIMEZONE}
```

Your input is:

```
Jul 15, 2015 9:33:23 AM
```

Either you change your input to fit the pattern or you define a different pattern. Following might suit your purpose:

```
 %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY}, %{YEAR} %{TIME}
```

Comment: I made a mistake in my sample, I meant to put %{CATALINA_DATESTAMP} which does match, and without the :logTimestamp portion, it passes... with the :logTimestamp it fails.

Comment: Which version of Logstash are you running? You might consider using _match_ instead of _pattern_ (_pattern_ is [deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-pattern)).

Comment: I was using 1.4.2 when this problem came up... I have since switched to 1.5.2 and have things working now